# HTML5 front-end button calls back-end Java method

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

User can add names into list which become visible at the page. I want to implement button which delete all data from the list. How I have to change my **HTML5** file to call Java method and what I have to do in server side to receive front-end call?

> Snippet from existing program.

[image]

> HTML5 page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Hello List!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello List!</h1>

        <ul>
            <li th:each="onePart : ${list}">
                <span th:text="${onePart}">hello world!</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Add content to list</h3>

        <form th:action="@{/}" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="content"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
        // Here is my button
        <button onclick="deleteList()">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Java file.

```
package wad.hellolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HelloListController {

    private List<String> list;

    public HelloListController() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.list.add("Hello list!");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String content) {
        if (content != null && !content.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.list.add(content.trim());
        }

        model.addAttribute("list", list);
        return "index";

    }
    // Method below needs something.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void deleteList() {
            this.list.clear();  
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you have it configured, any POST request to the root will clear the list. JavaScript function deleteList() { window.location.replace("/"); } should execute that code. Are you sure you want the @RequestMapping to point to the root? Consider using a less arbitrary path.

Comment: You can use AJAX to call server POST method and then refresh full page or partial page.